# Hibernate - Can @Where be used on parent entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose there's an `A` where conditionally contains B:

```
A:
  needs_B       Boolean
  B_Id        String

B:
  Id          String
```

How can I get the `B` in `A` only when `needs_B` is true ?(@Where annotation seems only works with attributes in target entity `B`)

I expect some code like:

```
public class A {
  @Column
  @Where(clause = "A.needs_B = 'true'")
  B b;
}
```

Comment: so `has_B` can be `true` and `B_Id` can be null? sounds like duplication

Comment: @ScaryWombat This may not be a good practical example, but I'd like to know if there's a solution.

Comment: see https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-where-clause - not sure why you think that it needs the `A.` prefix.

Comment: @ScaryWombat @Where clause only filter attributes in `B`. I don't know how to filter attributes in `A`.

Comment: The link I gave you shows it being done on a normal entity - are you saying that it is wrong?

Comment: @CDT did you found something about it?